# "Leaves" library for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, pixel

I'm writing an app for iOS to read the PDF documents and use "Leaves" library. Everything is cool except the white line with 1px width, that appears when you leaf over the page. Has anyone faced this before? How did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For me it works perfectly both for iphone and Ipad. But i never checked it with RETINA display. If you are using a device with retina display may be cause this issue. please check your app with a device doesn't has retina display may help you to find the issue.

Comment: Actually, the problem is on iPad 2, which haven't retina display.